# How to Share a local repository in the LAN through Subversive plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I am using subversive plugin in eclipse helios. Using this I have created a repository in my local drive.

**file:///D:/Sample_Repository/branches/phase1/MRT_Oct28**

Now I want to share this repositor to all the other team members. All those systems are also installed with subversive plugin.

All these systems are connected in the LAN.

Can anyone tell me how they can access this repository.

Answer (score 0):

To properly share a repository among multiple users/clients, you need to set up a proper Subversion server on a centralized system (**not** your PC!) which is backed up regularly.

The full details of setting up a server from scratch are beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer; [the Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.html) explains it quite well.

All of the pieces are available from Apache & the Subversion project (which falls under the Apache organization), or you can use a pre-packaged solution like CollabNet Subversion Edge, uberSVN or VisualSVN.

While it may be *technically possible* for you to share the repository over a UNC path using the file:/// protocol, it is not safe to do so and is not a recommended or supported configuration. It's not unlike giving all users unrestricted administrative access to every computer they touch - you can do it, but eventually you'll regret it.

Comment: It is ok. But for the time being, it is an immediate issue for me on how to share this repository to other team members using subversive plug-in in eclipse.

Comment: You can't. You cannot properly share a repository with other users via a *client*. You need to run a server. Full Stop.